# What does "System.IO" mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm in my first year studying .Net and came to the chapter, "An Introduction to the System.IO classes"

I'm just curious to know what the .IO stands for.  I do understand that this is learning about how to use Directories, Files and paths.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IO itself stands for Input/Output.

This is the entire `System.IO` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx

You're probably going to cover directories, files, and streams.

Answer (score 4):

'IO' is the standard acronym for Input/Output. The `System.IO` namespace contains all the classes that deal with input/outputs like reading/writing files.

Answer (score 3):

`IO` stands for `Input and Output`. Basically `System.IO` contains methods for reading and writing files as well as using `Streams` like you have said already.